# Advance sorting in Excel

Tags: excel

In our warehouse we have even/odd system of locations.

here is the example:

```
1-101-1
1-103-1
1-105-1
....
1-285-1
```

and

```
2-102-1
2-104-1
2-116-1
2-240-1
....
2-286-1
```

and have levels too

```
1-101-2
1-101-3
1-101-4
```

there have a lot of data, and I need sort like this:

example numbers:

```
1-101-1
2-130-1
1-131-1
1-150-2
2-132-3
3-229-5
4-262-1
4-286-5
7-267-1
5-239-1
6-270-1
7-267-3
```

I need sort like this:

```
1-101-1
2-130-1
1-131-1
2-132-3
4-286-5
4-262-1
3-229-5
5-239-1
6-270-1
7-267-1
7-267-1
```

point is first two numbers(**1**-101-1;**2**-102-1) goes from smallest to biggest, next two(**3**-285-1;**4**-286) goes from biggest to smallest and 
5 - 6 goes again from smallest to biggest and with that system to the end

second thing for sort is middle number, that number will goes as first from smallest to biggest, then from biggest to smallest, and last number is level, that is same as level 1 but must be sorted as level one, or be near level 1 if there is 7-267-1 and 7-267-3

is there any solution? thanks

edit:

[here is image for easier understanding because it is hard to explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvYPZ.png)

Thanks all for answers, especially Daniel who are an expert in Excel and understand what I need.

I mean there is not solution for sort like that without VBA, but Daniel show me that i was wrong. Thanks again.

That is what i need, but there are some errors, if you can help me with that

this is other example with other locations:

[this is unsorted locations with formulas you give me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qZis.png)

and this is sorted, but with bad order:

[bad sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yjET.png)

and here is with errors:

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57WkB.png)

we have 120 rows, and numbers bigger then 99 display error, and number 22-250-1 goes in -25 in second row

I try formula with numbers you enter in this example, and i got same good sort as you, but after entering other places, there is some bad sort.

Comment: Are they always going to be in the format #-###-#? Please explain in more detail why 4-286-5 is above 4-262-1

Comment: Your input list and output list have a different number of elements. Is that intentional?

Comment: The more I reread this, the less I understand the question. you have `4-286-5` before `4-262-1`. Why?

Comment: Your results don't seem to match up with your explanation.  If Prime sort is the first number, then all of the same numbers should be together, but they are not.

Comment: You may want to take the time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If it helps you can upload screen caps to https://imgur.com/ and link to them

Comment: I edited post and add image what route is in warehouse and what sort I need, @ Edeki Okoh, Adam: Yeah format is always #-###-# and 4-286-5 is before 4-262-1 because is that way of movement in warehouse, 3-4 goes down, from bigger to smaller, and 1-2 goes from smaller to bigger. Again, 5-6 goes from smaller to bigger, and 7-8 goes from bigger to smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

I think I understand what is being requested.  It's a bit difficult to explain but I'll give it a try.

The primary sorting is to be as follows:

1. If first digit is either `3` or `4`, then it should be in descending order else ascending.
2. If the middle 3-digits are from a `3` or `4` numbered sequence (see #1 above), then the middle pair should be in descending order.
3. All sequences should be in ascending based on their final digit.

My solution breaks the sequence into distinct columns:

For example, create three columns: `First`, `Second`, `Third`.

Formula for `First`:

> `=INT(LEFT(A2, 1))`

Formula for `Second`:

> `=INT(RIGHT(LEFT(A2,5), 3))`

Formula for `Third`:

> `=INT(RIGHT(A2,1))`

Next, we assign values for sorting these three fields:

Create a column labeled `First_Sort_Pair`:

> `=IF(OR(B2=1,B2=2),1,`
>   `IF(B2=3,3,`
>   `IF(B2=4,2,`
>   `IF(OR(B2=5,B2=6),4,`
>   `IF(OR(B2=7,B2=8),5,6)))))`

Create a column labeled `First_Sort`:

> `=IF(OR(B2=3, B2=4), 2, 1)`

Create a column labeled `Second_Sort`:

> `=IF(E2=4, 2, IF(E2=3, 3, 1))`

Create a column labeled `Sort_3_4`:

> `=IF(OR(B2=3,B2=4),RANK(C2,C:C,0),)`

You can now begin sorting:
[[image: Advanced Sorting[1]]

> Result:

You will now have your data sorted as intended:
[image: Advanced Sorting Results]